# What should i do when i have this error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int(*)[101]" in c++

Tags: c++, strassen

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void readMatrixA(int lenght)
{
    int matrixA[101][101];
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
            cin >> matrixA[i][j];
}

void readMatrixB(int lenght)
{
    int matrixB[101][101];
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
            cin >> matrixB[i][j];
}

void matrixMultiplication(int matrixA[101][101], int matrixB[101][101],int lenght)
{
    int i, j, matrixC[101][101];
    if (lenght <= 2)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
            {
                matrixC[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < lenght; k++)
                    matrixC[i][j] += matrixA[i][k] * matrixB[k][j];
            }
    }
    else
    {
        matrixC[1][1]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][1], matrixB[1][1], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][2], matrixB[2][1], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[1][2]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][1], matrixB[1][2], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][2], matrixB[2][2], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[2][1]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][1], matrixB[1][1], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][2], matrixB[2][1], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[2][2]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][1], matrixB[1][2], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][2], matrixB[2][2], lenght / 2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < lenght; j++)
        {
            cout << matrixC[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int lenght;
    cout << "Introduceti dimensiunea matricelor: "; cin >> lenght;
    int matrixA[101][101], matrixB[101][101], matrixC[101][101];
    cout << "Introduceti matricea A: ";
    readMatrixA(lenght);
    cout << "Introduceti matricea B: ";
    readMatrixB(lenght);
    matrixMultiplication(matrixA, matrixB, lenght);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code for Strassen's matrix multiplication written in visual studio. The code is using divide and conquer technique for square matrix.

Inside the "matrixMultiplication" function, where are those 4 rows of calls, i have this error "argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "int(*)[101]"" and i don't know what to do.

Those are the rows with error.

```
        matrixC[1][1]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][1], matrixB[1][1], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][2], matrixB[2][1], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[1][2]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][1], matrixB[1][2], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][2], matrixB[2][2], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[2][1]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][1], matrixB[1][1], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][2], matrixB[2][1], lenght / 2);
        matrixC[2][2]=matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][1], matrixB[1][2], lenght / 2) + matrixMultiplication(matrixA[2][2], matrixB[2][2], lenght / 2);
```

Comment: `matrixB[1][1]`is an `int`, and the function is waiting for a matrix

Comment: Those aren't your only errors. In the same lines, you are trying to assign the return value of a `void` function to elements of `matrixC`.

Comment: In your various read functions, you are reading into local matrices which is then discarded. In you main function you also have some local matrices (with the same name as the other ones) which are used uninitialised. Just because you use the same name doesn't mean they refer to the same objects.

Comment: *"The code is using divide and conquer technique for square matrix."* -- interestingly, I would advise the **programmer** to use a divide and conquer technique for debugging. Isolate the problem. Check each sub-expression in a problematic line for problems (e.g. try calling `matrixMultiplication(matrixA[1][1], matrixB[1][1], lenght / 2)` on its own line before calling it in your larger expression). Trim off code that is not needed to reproduce the error (don't worry about functionality -- there is no functionality until you fix compilation errors). Reduce to a [mre], where bugs cannot hide.

Comment: I'm afraid this program has never been in the same room with Strassen's multiplication. It resembles the naïve matrix multiplication if you squint hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MatrixMultiplication()` function you return a `void`, but your program is waiting for it to return an `int`. You need to change `MatrixMultiplication` to return an int.